# Kotlin: How to break line after equal sign for long expressions or declarations

Tags: kotlin, variables, multiline

In Python, I can do something like

```
long_declaration_and_long_variable_name = \
    foo_bar.this_is_a_really_long_function_name_and_its_only_getting_longer["baz"]
```

Is it possible to do something like this in Kotlin?

I am fully aware that in Kotlin you can break lines for for chaining, such as

```
val xyz = foo_bar.this_is_shorter
    .so_I_can_break(this_up)
    .into_individual_lines(like_so)
```

However, in my case the function name is very long and I would simply like to have it on the next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get you correctly but in Kotlin you can do the same as in Python (tbh even simpler because you don't need to use `\` sign)

```kotlin
val long_declaration_and_long_variable_name: SomeLongTypeName = 
    foo_bar.this_is_a_really_long_function_name_and_its_only_getting_longer("some long argument string")
```